# Getting started with automating web activities

Tags: python, web, automation, phantomjs

I'm trying to automate a few tasks and learn a new skill at the same time.
I figured this would be a good one to start with. I'd like to enter a range of data into this online calculator to save me manually doing it.

https://www.rba.gov.au/calculator/financialYearDecimal.html

I figure PhantomJS is a tool I could use, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

well one the tools for these kind of automation is called [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) it works with Chrome, Firefox, PhantomJS, and it's widely used for web automation.